# How to implement the OO in Javascript using prototype framework?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypejs

please give the example to me.
I want a class, which is a abstract class name "Person" ,
and two abstract class named "Male" and "Female", which extends "Person", 
and two concrete class named "Young man" which extends "Male" and "Young woman" which extends "Female".
Also, I need a multiple inherited class which called "Unknown", and it extends both "Male" and "Female"... ...

Thx in advance... 
(Using the Javascript prototype framework is allowed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be more that enough:

http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance

Comment: Be sure to use the new Class.create( *subclass*, { /* class code */ }) method